# GeoServer, WMS-T and time ranges

Tags: geoserver, wms, time

I have a case where WMS-T is desired, preferably using GeoServer. The input data contains two date fields with start and end date, which describes a timespan.

However, in GeoServer it seems that one can only specify one time field for dimensions.

Is there a way to get around this ?

I am thinking that one possible scenario would be to use PostGIS for serving data, and create a view/PL-pgSQL that does some of the logic.

Answer (score 1):

If using the WMS-T standard is a requirement or a way to solve your case, then you can use GeoServer parametrized [SQL layers](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html) and use your own time parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Current GeoServer (2015) supports defining an optional "End Attribute" for time in the Edit Layer/Dimensions tab.  Ref: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/webadmin/data/layers.html#webadmin-layers-edit-dimensions